# How to check if sql row contains any of the values?

Tags: php, mysql

I think I am missing something obvious here but... I have a user that sign up himself for a `$galleries=array('flowers','mountains','sky')`
And i saved that (imploded) in SQL row galleryTypes like that : `flowers,mountains,sky`

Now, how to select that user from table, when I'm searching for users with flowers and sky? 
I tried something like:

```
SELECT user FROM table WHERE galleryTypes = flowers OR galleryTypes = sky
```

But with no luck...

Can someone point me to the right direction ? 
Thanks!

Comment: what's the error or response of your query?

Comment: Use `FIND_IN_SET` as in the linked question.

Comment: But it would be better if you normalized your schema and used a many-to-many relationship table. `FIND_IN_SET` can't use indexes.

Comment: I better try rearrange that table with your suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
... WHERE galleryTypes IN ('flowers', 'mountains', 'sky')
```

would work **IF** `galleryTypes` contains ONLY a single value. If you're storing multiple values in that field, then you're in for a very very ugly time, and would be better off learning about [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: I guess I have to look that up, because any of current responses works for me :( Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT user FROM table WHERE galleryTypes LIKE '%flowers%' OR galleryTypes LIKE '%sky%'
```

But look out for existing substrings ('sky' will also match 'skyline' for example)! You can solve that problem by storing it like `,flowers,mountains,sky,` (so surrounded with comma's) and use this query:

```
SELECT user FROM table WHERE galleryTypes LIKE '%,flowers,%' OR galleryTypes LIKE '%,sky,%'
```